# Serializing static inner classes java

Tags: java, oop, static, static-classes

I'm making a game in Java at the moment and how I am planning on handling NPCs at the moment is having each NPC be an instance of their own unique class, all of which inherit from an abstract NPC class.

For example, if I have a character named 'Michael', Michael will be an instance of the Michael class, which will inherit from NPC.

While I was setting this up, it occured to me that perhaps I could have all the NPC classes defined as static classes within the body of the NPC class, mainly just because I will then only have the NPC.java file, and not a bunch of Michael.java, John.java, etc.

so this would look like

```
public abstract class NPC implements Seralizable {

   //stuff

   public static class Michael extends NPC {

      //more stuff

   } 

}
```

and when I need to create an instance of Michael in the game, it would look like

```
NPC npc1 = NPC.Michael();
```

As you can see above, NPC implements Seralizable, and this is so I can save the gamestate to a file. My main concern at the moment is if these inner static classes would do anything funny with serialization, as static *fields* are all transient.

I would also appreciate feedback on this style of organizing the code, and if people would normally just prefer having the classes in their own files

Comment: Why are you hard coding all of these classes? This is a design smell and is something that you really don't want to do. Instead, it would be much more straightforward to create a Npc class, and then create instances of them, each instance with different properties. Otherwise, if you're hard coding this stuff, you're really painting yourself into a bad corner.

Comment: And I think that your main question would be solved if you changed your program design as I suggested.

Comment: There is logic that is unique to every npc that cannot be handed in when the instance is constructed, for behaviour and dialogue and etc, so those methods are defined in the NPC class and then overwritten in the child classes

Comment: That isn't a hindrance and probably could be better handled with a few base Npc classes and use of an appropriate design pattern, such as perhaps the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

Comment: "*My main concern at the moment is if these inner static classes would do anything funny with serialization, as static fields are all transient.*" -- static nested classes are not the same as static fields and so you may be confusing different concepts here. Also, what happens when you try to serialize and deserialize?

Comment: BTW there is no *inner class* in posted code! From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3-100): "An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly `static`." (an inner class would need an instance of the enclosing class)

Comment: @user16320674 'static inner class' is _very_ common slang. In the end, words are tools used to convey ideas. If I say 'irregardless' and you know precisely what I mean, the word was a good tool. Even though irregardless "is not a word". Now, normally if a term is explicitly used by the core controlling spec (The JLS), then that gives a ton of credibility to it, but in the end, the only relevant question is __what does the majority of the community understand when you use that word__. And given how incredibly common e.g. "static inner class" is, that definition __is not The Final Word__.

Comment: The point is: Calling The `X` in `public class Foo { public static class X {}}` "an inner class" is mostly fine, if somewhat confusing. More to the point, calling the `X` in `public class Foo {public class X{}}` an 'inner class' and then assuming that the person you said that too will of course be clued in to know that this means it isn't static, that's you failing your job as communicator, because that's a really bad assumption to make. __Eventhough__ the JLS uses that term specifically to mean 'non static nested class'. What can I say? Communities trump specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static inner classes are identical to top-level classes in every way other than how they are named. Whether they serialize or not is utterly independent of the class they are inside of. There is no difference, whatsoever, between:

```
--- Michael.java:

public class Michael extends Npc { ... }

--- Npc.java

public class Npc implements Serializable { .... }
```

and

```
---- Npc.java

public class Npc implements Serializable {
  public static class Michael extends Npc { .... }
}
```

if `Michael` is not going to contain any custom code (just inherits from `Npc` but otherwise doesn't define anything different or new), Michael should not be its own class.

Comment: Of course, I agree with this, but any thoughts on the OP's code structure?

Comment: I can imagine each NPC has custom routines. There's the bartender in the village that has an `idling()` method where he takes out a rag and wipes down the counter. In fact, that specific behaviour is for a (as per the writing for the game, not the coding for it) specific barman, and in the script, that barman is called 'Michael'. There can in code be many michaels (anytime the main character walks close to the village it 'renders' and a michael object is made, when the main char walks away, the entire village despawns). Perhaps 2 different villages both have a 'Michael'.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm not sure it's the _best_ choice, but representing that barman script as its own class is sensible. Sticking that class as a static inner class in NPC is sensible (but the reason stated by OP, 'to reduce java files', really isn't). Calling that class `Michael` is.. probably also acceptable, really. I can see a world where this question makes sense, and it is not a preposterous series of events to get there. I think in the spirit of SO you should at that point give the question the benefit of the doubt. Note that this answer has an footnote in case this isn't accurate.

Comment: Thanks, you basically got it spot on with your barman example. It's that exact sort of behaviour that I needed to handle that made me think of doing it this way. I asked some others about this and they gave alternative clever solutions using lambda expressions or a 'prototype pattern', but I thought this way was the most concise and readable way of doing it.



also, maybe it still isn't sensible, but with the point about reducing java files, again that was moreso about readability/workflow. I didn't want to have to jump between differen't files when writing the behaviour for all the npcs.

Comment: Having relevant things close together is useful. 2 snippets of code that aren't in the same source file can't really be considered 'close together'. However, your solution, @user21749640 , also doesn't work: Now you have ginormous source file and stuff in there cannot be close together either. Hence why 'I want to reduce the number of java files' is a silly goal, and this would be a bad reason to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? If having relevant things close together is useful, then what is wrong with grouping the NPC classes together so I can have all of their behaviour nearby? Sorry, I've just read your comment a few times and I don't think I understand the wording.

Comment: Your `Npc.java` file will be very very large. This causes more problems than you end up solving.